# Where I am wrong? I am using Maven ProJect to make TODO application with hibernate ,JSP, SERVLET

Tags: database, hibernate, servlets

My Problem database connectvity
**WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: No suitable driver found for**
I faced problem with database connectivity .I am using Eclispse
Database 10g
Tomcat 8.5
Ojdbc 14

My Code is
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_Class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="connection.password">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">system</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect</property>
        <property name="hdm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.entities.Note"/>
       
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>

**SaveNoteServlet.java**




public class SaveNoteServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    
    public SaveNoteServlet() {
        super();
      
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            //title ,content fetch
            String title=request.getParameter("title");
            String content=request.getParameter("content");
            Note note=new Note(title,content,new Date());
            System.out.println(note);
            //hibernate :save
            Session ses=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            System.out.println(ses);
            Transaction t=ses.beginTransaction();
            ses.save(note);
            t.commit();
            ses.close();
            System.out.println("Tble created");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
    }

}

**HIbernateUtil.java**
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().
                build();

        SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBuilder.build();

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void close() {
        if(sessionFactory.isOpen()) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
 
Error code-

May 18, 2021 8:08:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion

INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.5.Final}

May 18, 2021 8:08:08 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>

INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}

May 18, 2021 8:08:08 PM
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure

WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL []
May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator

INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, driver_Class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, user=system}

    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM 
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    
    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
    WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState.getConnection()" because "this.state" is null
    
    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect
    
    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
    
    May 18, 2021 8:08:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: No suitable driver found for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same error, but after searching on various websites and trying their solutions I come to know that the dependency that you have included for MySQL should have the same version installed in your system.

In my case, this dependency works fine-

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

you can also try the different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Why the connection url property value left empty?

Below are the working properties, try it out and let me know for any issues.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">scott</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">tiger</property>
```

Comment: after addiing url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"also i get problem